# Buenas, soy nuevo en esta comunidad y en ámbito tecnológico y tengo una consulta sobre mi programa, específicamente en mi .CSS

Tags: html, css

Estoy seguro que es sonsa la pregunta pero aprovecho para poder aprender a interactuar en esta comunidad.
Quisiera que mi input en mi programa no este tan cerca a mi button primero pondré mi código HTML, luego mi CSS y al final adjuntare mi imagen. De todas formas muchas gracias.[image: mi input esta pegado a mi button (calcular)]

```
<input class="item" id="peso" type="number" placeholder="Peso en kg" />
```

```
input{
width: 70%;
padding: 12px 15px;
border: none;
background-color: #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero, pusiste en primer lugar la imagen. Segundo, puedes jugar con el atributo `margin` para lo que quieres hacer.

```
input{
margin: 10px; //aplica a los cuatro lados
width: 70%;
padding: 12px 15px;
border: none;
background-color: #eee;
}
```

Puedes encontrar más info [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/margin)